# Reference scss variable inside manifest.json

Tags: json, angular, sass

I am developing a PWA using Angular. I am using a centralized color file where I store the primary and secondary color for the app in scss variables.

color.palette.scss:

```
// other code
$treadwill-pre-login-primary: #2a3b3d;
$treadwill-pre-login-app-foreground: #f4bb56;
// other code
```

I want to refer to these variables from the manifest.json file.

manifest.json:

```
{
 ..
 "background_color": $treadwill-pre-login-app-foreground,
 "theme_color": $treadwill-pre-login-primary
 ..
}
```

Relative file structure:

```
|
-- ... 
-- /app
--index.html
--color.palette.scss
--manifest.json
-- ...
```

Is there a way to do it?